# Loop to Match Parts of List

Tags: python

My code:

```
#prints out samenodes
f = open('newerfile.txt')
mylist = list(f)
count = 0
i = 1
while count < 1000:
    if mylist[i] == mylist[i+12] and mylist [i+3] == mylist [i+14]: 
        print mylist[i]
    count = count+1
        i = i+12
```

My intention is to look at elt 1, elt 2. If elt 1 == elt 13 AND elt 2==elt 14 I want to print elt 1. Then, I want to look at elt 13 and elt 14. If elt 2 matches elt 13+12 AND elt 14 matches elt 14+12 I want to print it. ETC...

There are certainly parts of my list that fit this criteria, but the program returns no output.

Comment: Are the `elt` supposed to be whole lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To iterate over multiple lists (technically, iterables) in "lockstep", you can use [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=zip#zip).  In this case, you want to iterate over four versions of `mylist`, offset by 0, 12, 2 and 13.

```
zippedLists = zip(mylist, mylist[12:], mylist[2:], mylist[13:])
```

Next, you want the 0th, 12th, 24th, etc elements.  This is done with slice:

```
slicedList = zippedLists[::12]
```

Then you can iterate over that:

```
for elt1, elt13, elt2, elt14 in slicedList:
    if elt1 == elt13 and elt2 == elt14:
        print elt1
```

Putting it together with the file operations, we get

```
#prints out samenodes
f = open('newerfile.txt')
mylist = list(f)

zippedLists = zip(mylist, mylist[12:], mylist[2:], mylist[13:])
slicedList = zippedLists[::12]

for elt1, elt13, elt2, elt14 in slicedList:
    if elt1 == elt13 and elt2 == elt14:
        print elt1
```

Code like this is generally considered more "pythonic" than your current version, as using list indexes are generally discouraged when you are iterating over the list.

Note that if you've got a huge number of elements in your list the above code creates (and destroys at some point) five extra lists. Therefore, you may get better memory performance if you use the equivalent functions in [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html), which uses lazy iterators to prevent copying lists needlessly:

```
from itertools import islice, izip

#prints out samenodes
f = open('newerfile.txt')
mylist = list(f)

zippedLists = itertools.izip(mylist, islice(mylist, 12), islice(mylist, 2), islice(mylist, 13))
slicedList = itertools.islice(zippedLists, 0, None, 12)

for elt1, elt13, elt2, elt14 in slicedList:
    if elt1 == elt13 and elt2 == elt14:
        print elt1
```

There's probably a way in `itertools` to avoid slurping the entire file into `mylist`, but I'm not sure I remember what it is - I think that is the use case for [`itertools.tee`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee).

Answer (score 3):

One problem is your indices.  Be advised that lists begin with an index of 0.

I'm surprised nobody's answered this yet:

```
#prints out samenodes
f = open('newerfile.txt')
mylist = list(f)
count = 0
i = 0
while count < 1000:
    #print mylist[i]
    #print mylist[i+12]
    #print mylist[i+13]
    #print mylist[i+14]
    #...use prints to help you debug
    if mylist[i] == mylist[i+12] and mylist [i+1] == mylist [i+13]: 
        print mylist[i]
    count = count+1
    i = i+12
```

This is probably what you want.